# How to default a value in select tag while using ngModel in Angular 6?

Tags: angular

I have this below code in Angular 6:

```
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" #ig="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="assetFormDetails.ig">
                <option value="" >Select Ig</option> 
                <option *ngFor="let ig of igList" value="{{ig.igName}}">{{ig.igName}}</option>
            </select>
```

When I am getting the value of `assetFormDetails.ig` as `''` or `null` , it is not selecting the node `<option value="" >Select Ig</option>` . Instead it is creating and selecting a new blank node on the drop-down list.

How can I make it select this node: `<option value="" >Select Ig</option>` in this case.

Comment: can you check my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

simply just give a `assetFormDetails.ig` a intial value

as example

```
<select class="form-control" #ig="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="assetFormDetails.ig">
    <option value="" >Select Ig</option> 
     <option *ngFor="let ig of [1,2,3,4,5]" value="{{ig}}">{{ig}}</option>
</select>
```

component

```
  assetFormDetails = {ig:"3"}; //   assetFormDetails = {ig:""} Select Ig
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-53703421)

Answer (score 0):

I just added name attribute to the select tag, it just worked fine. like `name="ig"`

```
<select class="form-control" name="ig" #ig="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="assetFormDetails.ig">
    <option value="" >Select Ig</option> 
     <option *ngFor="let ig of [1,2,3,4,5]" value="{{ig}}">{{ig}}</option>
</select>
```

I am not sure, but it seems "name" attribute is required in a template driven form.